# changing value in gameloop

Tags: java, android, libgdx, game-loop

I have a variable `tail`. I set a value for this variable when creating constructor. And I have a `changeTail()` method which changes tail periodically by 10 pixels (increases 10 pixels and then decreases 10 pixels). 
This method is called in `update` method so this is continuous.

I have another method `speedUp()` which when score increases by 10 it speeds up player. To get the scores current value this is also called in `update` method.
So, when I want to speed up game I also want to make tail longer. So I set a new value for tail using `speedUp()`.

But the problem is, because of `speedUp()` being called in the `update` method it keeps setting the same value for `tail` and now `tail` does not change like it used to do before speed up.

Here is my code:

```
class Game{
   float tail; 
   boolean increasing;  
   int score;  

   public Game(){
    tail = 60;
    increasing = false;
    score = 0;
   }

   public void changeTail(){
     if(increasing){
       tail += 1;
       if(tail >= 60){
         increasing = false;
       }
     }else{
       tail -= 1;
       if(tail <=50){
         increasing = true;
       }
     }    
   }

   public void speedUp(){

     if(score >= 20){
      //player speed up
      tail = 70;
     }

   }

   public void update(){
     tailChange();
     speedUp();
   }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to comprehend what exactly are you trying to achieve from your code and description. Could you restructure your question, simplify it? For now, I can guess, that in your `speedUp()` method you should have `tail += 10` instead of `tail = 70`, and also increase by 10 max and min values of tail in `tailChange()`.

Comment: what i am trying to do is this: in the beginning tail was changing in this interval 50-60.  if score gets more than 20 tail should change between 60-70. but i check score in speedUp() and it keeps being called 60 times in a second so instead of setting value of tail just once and changing it in interval of 60-70 it keeps assigning value of tail to 70 so tail does not change its value. i hope it is more clear :)

Comment: maybe having one more variable defining currentTailSize, and your if being based on that value. something like   if(tail >= currentTailSize)...   currenttailsize only being updated on the speedUp() method. Hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry i see it now. i already shared the solutoin

Answer (score 0):

Add additional variable `maxTail`, and increase it by 10 when `score` is >= 20. And in `tailChange()` vary the `tail` between `maxTail` and `maxTail - 10`.

```
public class Game {

    float maxTail;
    float tail;
    boolean increasing;

    int score;
    int nextScoreGoal;

    public Game() {
        maxTail = 60;
        tail = maxTail;
        increasing = false;

        score = 0;
        nextScoreGoal = 20;
    }

    public void update() {
        tailChange();

        if (score >= nextScoreGoal) {
            nextScoreGoal += 20; // I assume that you will keep increasing tail?
            speedUp();
        }
    }

    public void tailChange() {
        if (increasing) {
            tail++;
            if (tail >= maxTail) {
                increasing = false;
            }
        } else {
            tail--;
            if (tail <= maxTail - 10) {
                increasing = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public void speedUp() {
        maxTail += 10;
        tail += 10;
    }
}
```

Or just put `speedUp()` method out of `update()`, i.e. call it where you increase the `score`.

Comment: if score will be more than 20 it will keep increasing values of maxTail and tail, will not it?

Comment: no problem, i think i have found the solution with another way. i will share if it works

Comment: Sure, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

after reading this ( https://answers.unity.com/questions/1193588/how-to-only-update-once-in-update-function.html ) i have found answer. so, instead of trying to set value of tail in speedUp() i set it when score increases. for example score increases when collides with a brick:

```
public void brickCollision(){
  if(/*check if collides with brick*/){
    score +=1;
    if(score >=20){
     tail = 70;
    }
  }

}
```

and it work perfectly now. time to solve other bugs :)